# What causes the MS-Access error: "Unknown"?

Tags: ms-access

I recently tried running a query in MS Access, which resulted in the following "Unknown" error:

[image: MS-Access "Unknown" error]

After a short web search, it looked as though it might indicate a DB corruption - as mentioned in [this Microsoft answers forum thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/unknown-error-when-opening-table-in-access-2010/ab77a804-4773-400a-afa5-9b1ec69c0eb2) and in [this MSDN social forum thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/830cef20-086a-4e88-86db-3038698eac07/unknown-error-while-opening-a-query?forum=accessdev). However, in the second of these, the OP appeared to fix the problem in some other, unspecified way. I checked again on Stack, and I checked on [Allen Browne's most excellent repository of MS Access information](http://allenbrowne.com/tips.html) (which incidentally provides some useful tips if you *do* have a DB Corruption and need to repair it), but didn't see this error mentioned at all. I continued to investigate my particular instance and found what I did wrong in my case.

As this error is not very descriptive and appears to be caused by more than one possible issue, it might help to have a list of possible causes that people can try to fix if they receive this error, so I decided to raise this question and answer it for my case. If anyone knows of other causes for this "Unknown" error, that might help other people searching later...

I'm using MS Access with Office 365, but I've tagged the question with the more general tag, as I expect it to be an issue with more than one version of MS Access.

A couple more links that provided different suggestions: [this Access forums thread](https://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=64608) has a few other suggestions (as usual starting with 'DB is corrupted' but then going on to mention improper fieldnames, exceeding DB limitations and having invalid characters in source data), and there's another suggestion about an MS Access driver in [this PCReview forum thread](https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/microsoft-office-access-unknown-error.3848957/) in a case where the error appeared on one computer, but not a different one. They don't fit my use-case, but might be useful to someone else who gets this error.

(Btw, I believe this will be my first SO question - if there are problems, please help me improve it :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the error showed up with a couple of queries and not all of them (so less likely to be a DB corruption and more likely to be a problem with those queries).  When I checked one query and a previous version of it that still worked, I saw that the main difference was that I had added a criterion referencing a control on a form. Normally, I would run this query from a button on that form, but on this occasion I ran the query directly and the form was not open. (D'Oh!)

That in itself would have given me a more descriptive error message about a missing parameter, except that I was using Eval() to evaluate the parameter using late binding (`<=Eval("[Forms]![MyFormF]![cmbMyControl]"` instead of `<=[Forms]![MyForm]![cmbMyControl]`).

It appears that in this case, Access can't work out what is happening and just tells the user that there is a problem.